# Are there any special kind of rituals mentioned for saptami of bhadrapad?

Tags: scripture, puranas, dharma-shastras

In gujarat, people completely shuts off their stoves where they cook their food daily and install a plant over it(forgot the name). Then, in that day and later in janmashtami they don't cook food but eat the pre made food.

Does any shastra mentions this or any other rituals in saptami?

Comment: A similar practice is also observed in rural parts of Western Bengal. There cooking is abandoned on the day of Simha samkranti (the last day of solar Bhadra month) & people would consume food prepared on the previous day after offering it to Manasa, the presiding deity of snakes who is widely revered by Bengali, Axomiya & Maithili people. In the past snakes were a large menace in Bengal, so Manasa's worship to repel snakes was (& is) widespread across the region. However, this practice has no scriptural sanction, as Smriti texts prohibit eating food which hasn't been eaten overnight.

Comment: @অনু really interesting. Here, these are done to worship maa shitala, and afaik she too is related to snakes somehow if i remember correctly.